# Flow for transfering encrypted data between server and client

Tags: php, file, client, encryption

I am creating an online organiser for use in various places, it will deal with sensitive information such as invoices, contact details, private memos etc

Target platform(s) are standard shared hosting site (PHP5/SQL) and any JS capable browser the client wants to view the organiser with.

Data is stored in a single XML file. What is the best way to transfer data from the server to client for reading, then back from client to server for updating, without compromising the users password or the data in the file?

The data will ideally be stored encrypted so that even if an attacker gains entry to the server they won't be able to access the information. The server must also be able to accept incoming data, and check it is from a reliable source, so that attackers can't tamper.

One idea I had was to store the XML in a file encrypted with the users password. This way the password would not have to be transmitted from client to server. When I wanted to send data back from the client to server, I could send a hashed password that the server can use to identify the client as legitimate... however, the password would still have to be transmitted on website setup/password change.

I've been coding for ages but am kind of new to the workflow for handling sensitive data.. So I'm not looking for code but rather someone to give me a few hints?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds like a case for HTTPS

Comment: As a side note: I thought about putting a secret key INSIDE the encrypted file, which the client could read upon decrytion, then use to identify itself as legitimate when sending encrypted data back to the server. However if the key was intercepted then attackers could tamper..... 

I also thought about storing the password in a server-side folder inaccessible from the web, then using that to decrypt incoming data. This would completely avoid transmitting the password, but I assume that storing the password unhashed is very very bad practise

Comment: Is there anything that I can do for customers who insist on using crap hosts that don't sell SSL certificates?

Comment: I don't think so. Trying to rebuild HTTPS for servers that don't offer it sounds like a really bad idea. Tell them they need to move away from the crap host, or have an insecure system... this is only part of your requirement, though, encrypting data on server side is a legitimate issue not covered by HTTPS, that just encrypts the client-server communication. It's still a prerequisite for anything else you choose to do in this department.

Comment: Just a thought, maybe have a login page, once they login you store the user's IP address and let them download. Then when one is uploaded it verifies someone has logged in from that IP in the last few minutes. If they haven't force them to login again before they can upload.

Comment: Or why not just build the upload feature into a password protected section of the website? How were you planning on them uploading the files?

Comment: Pitchinnate - Not bad ideas, but IP address isn't absolutely reliable (I think it can be spoofed) and uploading to a password protected would still require transmitting the password in some form.